# recursively merge all files under a root directory

Tags: shell, merge

I need to recursively merge all csv files under a root directory(arbitrary hierarchy), the csv files might not have a line break at the very end, so I would like to add a new line whenever I merge two files.
how do I do this in shellscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find with two -exec options:

```
find $YOUR_DIR -iname '*.csv' -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \;
```

**Edit**: also, maybe if your CSVs have a header, instead of `cat`, you may use `sed 1d` to supress the first line:

```
find $YOUR_DIR -iname '*.csv' -exec sed 1d {} \; -exec echo \;
```

Comment: Is there a way to echo the name of each file instead of a new line?

Comment: yes, pass `\{}` as argument to echo, like this: `echo \{} \;`. The program `find` will replace those brackets with the file name, but you need to escape it so the shell won't try to interpret.